# How to broadcast to a specific room with SocketIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

The issue is with `socket.broadcast.to('roomName')`.

We have tried everything but it's not working. We checked that the users are joining the room correctly. When we are broadcasting to everyone it's working perfectly but when we are sending it to a specific room nothing is happening.

Here is the backend code:

```
const express = require("express");
const socketio = require("socket.io");
const http = require("http");
const {
  getUserById,
  getUsersByroom,
  addUser,
  removeUser,
} = require("./utils/user.js");
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const io = socketio(server);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("New connection");
  //console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);
  //console.log(io.sockets);
  // socket.on("canvas-data", (data, { username, room }) => {
  //   console.log(room);
  //   if (data) socket.broadcast.to(room).emit("canvas", data);
  // });
  socket.on("join", ({ username, room }, callback) => {
    room = room.trim().toUpperCase();
    //console.log(room);
    socket.join(room);
    //console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);
    //console.log(io.sockets);
    const id = socket.id;
    const { error, message } = addUser({ username, id, room });
    callback({ error, message });
  });
  socket.on("addFigure", ({ figure, username, room }) => {
    room = room.trim().toUpperCase();
    console.log(figure, room);
    console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);
    console.log(io.sockets.adapter.sids);
    io.in("JS").emit("addFigure", figure);
  });
  socket.on("disconnectUser", ({ username, room }) => {
    const user = removeUser(socket.id);
    console.log(user);
  });
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    const user = removeUser(socket.id);
    console.log(user);
  });
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

here is the frontEnd code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router";
import "./Board.css";

let context = null;
function Board({
  lineColor,
  lineWidth,
  socket,
  shapeType,
  setshapeType,
  eraserSize,
}) {
  let shape = "pencil";
  let pencilCoords = [];
  let { room, username } = useParams();
  let [strokeColor, setstrokeColor] = useState(lineColor);
  let [allFigures, setallFigures] = useState([]);
  let [deletedFigures, setDeletedFigures] = useState([]);

  function createNewElement(x) {
    const len = localStorage.getItem("len");
  
    setallFigures((prevState) => [...prevState.slice(0, len - 1), x]);
   
  }
  useEffect(() => {
//this is the socket.io code 
    socket.on("addFigure", (figure) => {
      console.log(figure);
      setallFigures((prevState) => [...prevState, figure]);
      const len = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("len"));
      localStorage.setItem("len", len + 1);
    });
    if (localStorage.getItem("len") === null) localStorage.setItem("len", 0);
    if (localStorage.getItem("toolName") === null)
      localStorage.setItem("toolName", "pencil");
    localStorage.setItem("lineWidth", lineWidth);
    localStorage.setItem("strokeColor", strokeColor);
 
    const figures = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("figures"));
    if (figures != null && figures.length > 0) setallFigures([...figures]);
   
    const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");

    canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 7.5;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 6;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.strokeStyle = lineColor;
    context = ctx;

    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", finisedPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
      draw(e);
    });
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [shape]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (context !== null) {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
   
      for (let i = 0; i < allFigures.length; i++) {
        context.lineWidth = allFigures[i].lineWidth;
        context.strokeStyle = allFigures[i].strokeColor;
        if (allFigures[i].type === "rect") {
          context.strokeRect(
            allFigures[i].x,
            allFigures[i].y,
            allFigures[i].w,
            allFigures[i].h
          );
        } else if (allFigures[i].type === "pencil") {
          const coords = allFigures[i].coords;
          for (var j = 1; j < coords.length; j++) {
            context.lineTo(coords[j].x, coords[j].y);
            context.stroke();
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(coords[j].x, coords[j].y);
          }
        } else if (allFigures[i].type === "circle") {
          context.beginPath();
          context.ellipse(
            allFigures[i].x,
            allFigures[i].y,
            allFigures[i].radiusX,
            allFigures[i].radiusY,
            0,
            0,
            2 * Math.PI
          );
          context.stroke();
        } else if (allFigures[i].type === "line") {
          context.beginPath();
          context.moveTo(allFigures[i].x, allFigures[i].y);
          context.lineTo(allFigures[i].endX, allFigures[i].endY);
          context.stroke();
        }
        context.beginPath();
      }
    }
    localStorage.setItem("figures", JSON.stringify(allFigures));
  }, [allFigures]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (context != null) {
      context.lineWidth = lineWidth;
      localStorage.setItem("lineWidth", lineWidth);
    }
  }, [lineWidth]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setstrokeColor(lineColor);
    localStorage.setItem("strokeColor", lineColor);
  }, [lineColor]);
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("eraserSize", eraserSize);
  }, [eraserSize]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (context !== null) {
      context.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
    }
  }, [strokeColor]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (context != null) {
      if (shapeType === "clear") {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        setallFigures([]);
        localStorage.setItem("len", 0);
        setshapeType(localStorage.getItem("toolName"));
      } else if (shapeType === "undo") {
        const len = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("len"));
        if (len > 0) {
          const element = allFigures[len - 1];
          setallFigures((prevState) => [...prevState.slice(0, len - 1)]);
          setDeletedFigures([...deletedFigures, element]);
          localStorage.setItem("len", len - 1);
          setshapeType(localStorage.getItem("toolName"));
        }
      } else if (shapeType === "redo") {
        if (deletedFigures.length > 0) {
          console.log(deletedFigures.length);
          const element = deletedFigures[deletedFigures.length - 1];
          setallFigures([...allFigures, element]);
          setDeletedFigures([
            ...deletedFigures.slice(0, deletedFigures.length - 1),
          ]);
          const len = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("len"));
          localStorage.setItem("len", len + 1);
          setshapeType(localStorage.getItem("toolName"));
        }
      }
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [shapeType]);
  let painting = false;
  let startX, startY;

  function startPosition(e) {
    painting = true;
    startX = e.clientX;
    startY = e.clientY;
    setDeletedFigures([]);
    pencilCoords = [];
    shape = localStorage.getItem("toolName");
    const len = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("len"));
    localStorage.setItem("len", len + 1);
    //draw(e);
  }

  function finisedPosition(e) {
    painting = false;
    if (context != null) {
      context.beginPath();
      const figures = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("figures"));
      const figure = figures[figures.length - 1];
      socket.emit("addFigure", { figure, username, room });
    }
  }

  let timeout;

  function draw(e) {
    if (!painting) return;
    if (context != null) {
      
      if (shape === "pencil") {
        pencilCoords.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
        let updatedPencil = {
          type: "pencil",
          coords: pencilCoords,
          lineWidth: localStorage.getItem("lineWidth"),
          strokeColor: localStorage.getItem("strokeColor"),
        };
        createNewElement(updatedPencil);
      } else if (shape === "rect") {
        let updatedRect = {
          type: "rect",
          x: startX,
          y: startY,
          w: e.clientX - startX + 1,
          h: e.clientY - startY + 1,
          lineWidth: localStorage.getItem("lineWidth"),
          strokeColor: localStorage.getItem("strokeColor"),
        };
        createNewElement(updatedRect);
      } else if (shape === "circle") {
        let updatedCircle = {
          type: "circle",
          x: (startX + e.clientX) / 2,
          y: (startY + e.clientY) / 2,
          radiusX: Math.abs((e.clientX - startX) / 2),
          radiusY: Math.abs((e.clientY - startY) / 2),
          lineWidth: localStorage.getItem("lineWidth"),
          strokeColor: localStorage.getItem("strokeColor"),
        };
        createNewElement(updatedCircle);
      } else if (shape === "line") {
        let updatedLine = {
          type: "line",
          x: startX,
          y: startY,
          endX: e.clientX,
          endY: e.clientY,
          lineWidth: localStorage.getItem("lineWidth"),
          strokeColor: localStorage.getItem("strokeColor"),
        };
        createNewElement(updatedLine);
      } else if (shape === "erase") {
        pencilCoords.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
        let updatedPencil = {
          type: "pencil",
          coords: pencilCoords,
          lineWidth: parseInt(localStorage.getItem("eraserSize")),
          strokeColor: "white",
        };
        createNewElement(updatedPencil);
      }

      context.beginPath();
      context.stroke();
      if (timeout !== undefined) clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        const base64image = document
          .querySelector("#canvas")
          .toDataURL("image/png");
        socket.emit("canvas-data", base64image, { username, room });
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  // socket.on("canvas", (data) => {
  //   console.log(data);
  //   let interval = setInterval(() => {
  //     if (painting) return;
  //     painting = true;
  //     clearInterval(interval);
  //     console.log("Canvas Data", data);
  //     let image = new Image();
  //     image.onload = () => {
  //       context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  //       painting = false;
  //     };
  //     image.src = data;
  //   }, 200);
  // });

  return <canvas className="board" id="canvas"></canvas>;
}

export default Board;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to emit a specific message to the people in a specific room you could do:

```
io.sockets.in(room).emit('something', something);
```

Comment: Can you also attach to the question your frontend code with sockets, to reproduce your error? Because everything on the backend looks fine, the error might be in your frontend code

Comment: Added! its not giving any error its just not working